# How slice Numpy array by column value

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like this numpy array

```
 dd =[[0.567 2 0.611]
      [0.469 1 0.479]
      [0.220 2 0.269]
      [0.480 1 0.508]
      [0.324 1 0.324]]
```

I need 2 seperate array `dd[:,1] ==1` and `dd[:,1] ==2`

These array are what I am after:

```
 na =[[0.469 1 0.479]
      [0.480 1 0.508]
      [0.324 1 0.324]]

 na2 =[[0.567 2 0.611]
       [0.220 2 0.269]]
```

I have tried `np.where` did really work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use numpy fancy indexing:

```
[~/repo/py]
|32>dd[dd[:,1] == 1]
[32] 
array([[ 0.469,  1.   ,  0.479],
       [ 0.48 ,  1.   ,  0.508],
       [ 0.324,  1.   ,  0.324]])

[~/repo/py]
|33>dd[dd[:,1] == 2]
[33] 
array([[ 0.567,  2.   ,  0.611],
       [ 0.22 ,  2.   ,  0.269]])
```

Alternatively you could use a list comprehension:

```
[~/repo/py]
|21>np.array([row for row in dd if row[1] == 1])
[21] 
array([[ 0.469,  1.   ,  0.479],
       [ 0.48 ,  1.   ,  0.508],
       [ 0.324,  1.   ,  0.324]])

[~/repo/py]
|22>np.array([row for row in dd if row[1] == 2])
[22] 
array([[ 0.567,  2.   ,  0.611],
       [ 0.22 ,  2.   ,  0.269]])
```

**edit:**

how to time these things in ipython:

```
[~/repo/py]
|36>timeit dd[dd[:,1] == 1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 6 us per loop

[~/repo/py]
|37>timeit np.array([row for row in dd if row[1] == 1])
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.5 us per loop
```

Comment: the first example (fancy indexing) is about twice as fast.