# How can I slice a numpy array by the value of the ith field?

Tags: arrays, numpy, split, pandas

I have a 2D numpy array with 4 columns and a lot of rows (>10000, this number is not fixed).

I need to create *n* subarrays by the value of one of the columns; the closest question I found was [How slice Numpy array by column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577443/how-slice-numpy-array-by-column-value); nevertheless, I dont know the exact values in the field (they're floats and they change in every file I need), but I know they are no more than 20.

I guess I could read line by line, record the different values and then make the split, but I figure there is a more efficient way to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can use multidimensional slicing conveniently:

```
import numpy as np

# just creating a random 2d array.
a = (np.random.random((10, 5)) * 100).astype(int)
print a
print

# select by the values of the 3rd column, selecting out more than 50.
b = a[a[:, 2] > 50]

# showing the rows for which the 3rd column value is > 50.
print b
```

Another example, closer to what you are asking in the comment (?):

```
import numpy as np

# just creating a random 2d array.
a = np.random.random((10000, 5)) * 100
print a
print

# select by the values of the 3rd column, selecting out more than 50.
b = a[a[:, 2] > 50.0]
b = b[b[:, 2] <= 50.2]

# showing the rows for which the 3rd column value is > 50.
print b
```

This selects out rows for which the 3rd column values are (50, 50.2].

Comment: well, but the values are very close, i tried using pandas but i got lost on the way.

Comment: @user1621048 I don't know what really changes, but I added another example a bit closer to what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for that task and more specifically the [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) method of DataFrame. Here's some example code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate a random 20x5 DataFrame
x=np.random.randint(0,10,100)
x.shape=(20,5)
df=pd.DataFrame(x)

# group by the values in the 1st column
g=df.groupby(0)

# make a dict with the numbers from the 1st column as keys and
# the slice of the DataFrame corresponding to each number as
# values of the dict
d={k:v for (k,v) in g}
```

Some sample output:

```
In [74]: d[3]
Out[74]: 
    0  1  2  3  4
2   3  2  5  4  3
5   3  9  4  3  2
12  3  3  9  6  2
16  3  2  1  6  5
17  3  5  3  1  8
```

Comment: The question is about numpy, not pandas. pandas has speed and memory disadvantages over numpy.